# Generics - Collections sort method

Tags: java, generics

When using `Collections.sort(List<T> list)`, with `List<Employee>`, where `Employee` is a class which does not extend `Comparable` interface.

Then I see following compilation error

> The method `sort(List<T>)` in the type `Collections` is not applicable for the arguments (`List<Employee>`).

I dont understand why `T` should implement `Comparable`, it's not specified anywhere in the method arguments of `sort` method.

Update : Please stop downvoting. I always thought only method parameter decides what to be passed as argument, but I see `<T extends Comparable<? super T>>` in the method signature but its not I see in any method signature. Access modifier, static or not ,return type, name of method are known to me, but what is the extra one?

Update : I was not aware of this : "All generic method declarations have a type parameter section delimited by angle brackets (< and >) that precedes the method's return type"

Comment: Yes it is: [`public static <T extends Comparable<? super T>> void sort(List<T> list)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#sort%28java.util.List%29)

Comment: As a general rule, if you can't do something manually (even if slowly :) ), then neither can a computer. So with that in mind: if I gave you a list of FooBars, with no information about what a FooBar is, and asked you to sort them -- how would you do it? The two answers are for a FooBar to be able to tell you how to sort itself (ie, it's Comparable) or for you to also tell me how to compare them (ie, passing in a Comparator).

Comment: I just dont understand what `<T extends Comparable<? super T>>` is in a method signature. Its not access modifier, return type, method name, then whats it?

Comment: `<T extends Comparable<? super T>>` means that the type `T` implements all of the methods declared in the `Comparable` interface. `Comparable` itself is a generic interface that requires that the types it operates on have to be of type `T` or a superclass of `T`. You can see [the tutorials](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/bounded.html) for more information.

Comment: Last update was very useful to me

Answer (score 5):

here's the complete signature :

```
public static <T extends Comparable<? super T>> void sort(List<T> list)
```

as you can see `T` must implement `Comparable` otherwise how will `sort()` know how to sort the `List<T>`

Comment: What is <T extends Comparable<? super T>>  in a method signature? Is It a special feature for declaring type of generics?

Comment: `<T extends Comparable<? super T>>` means that the type `T` implements all of the methods declared in the `Comparable` interface. `Comparable` itself is a generic interface that requires that the types it operates on have to be of type `T` or a superclass of `T`.

Answer (score 4):

```
public static <T extends Comparable<? super T>> void sort(List<T> list)
```

If you don't know which employee is greater than the other you can't sort. Just add in a custom Comparator.

Answer (score 0):

For primitive data types such as int, long, float etc the comparison is pre defined.
And sort takes in the predefined comparison measures and sorts your variables.

However, when you make a class, a class can be composed of many different primitive types and even other objects. Java cannot automatically know how to compare and so it needs to extend the comparable interface and define functions that specify how to sort. For e.g.

```
Class car {
int id; 
String name;
String company;
}
```

After implementing comparable you can define if your sorting depends on the id of the cars, its name or company name.
Hope this clears the need a bit.

Answer (score 0):

With generics, there are two approaches: 1. Wild cards and 2.Bounded type parameter.

Example with Wild cards :
`public  void sort(List<? extends T> list)`

Example with Bounded type  :
`public static <T extends Comparable<? super T>> void sort(List<T> list)`

Bounded type is preferred when `T needs to be used more than once, like in  the above example.